# Is it possible to load large PDF containing image faster?

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

Part of application I've created shows informations about scanned product, part of which is its label that i need to load from another server which works as storage. But their size is inconsistient (I sadly can't change it) ranging from half a MB to 20MB or more. And here is my problem the end-user can only see the info for max 9s and for bigger pdf's the loading takes most of this time.

The File on that page is loaded like that

```
document.querySelector('#etykieta').innerHTML = `<embed type='application/pdf' src=\"http://${pdfServerIP}/pdf/?path=${etkPath}&file=${etykieta}\">`;
```

And on the server that holds PDF's it looks like that (I couldn't make it load the pdf directly from shared directory on synology cloud so I ended with this workaround)

```
if ($handle = opendir($pth)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

        $pl = substr($file, 0, $dl);
        if ($pl == $plik) {
            $jest++;
            echo "{$file}<BR>";
            header("Content-type:application/pdf");
            readfile("{$pth}{$file}");
            exit;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

So is there any way to make the PDF's load faster without editing the files?

Comment: `echo "{$file}<BR>";` will bork the response, also `path` and `file` are vulnerable to LFI attack, your php is essentually `echo file_get_contents($_GET['path'].$_GET['file'])` nothing good can come of that

Comment: You can't... loading the pdf will depend on the user's network download speed since well the pdf is always downloaded into the local memory first before preview..

Comment: 1. Faster disks. 2. Faster network. 3. More than 9 seconds. 4. Use JS to pre-load the file in the background.

Comment: Welp, that's what I thought. Also preloading files would also not come into play bc they weight in total around 1gb and I have no means to know which will be used beforehand. Anyway thanks